# Using VS Code JSHint on EJS files

Tags: visual-studio-code, ejs, jshint

I have a node.js project with **js** and **ejs** files.
VS Code JSHint extension works fine on js files but ignores ejs files.
How can I get JSHint to lint ejs files? (I know the --extra-ext CLI flag but I don't know how to use it in VS Code).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install "EJS-Lint" `npm install ejs-lint` globally or locally,Jshint cant do what you need, look at here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-lint.
Good luck.